# How to remove ambiguity from the following grammar S -> aSbS | bSaS | epsilon

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I've been struggling for 4 days to remove ambiguity from the following grammar **S -> aSbS | bSaS | epsilon**.
I've learned that by eliminating left recursion and left factoring we can eliminate ambiguity.
But the problem seems really hard to me.

If I do left factoring what should be replaced? can't see any common prefixes.

Comment: "I've learned that by eliminating left recursion and left factoring we can eliminate ambiguity." Where did you learn that? It's not true. Eliminating left recursion can make top-down parsing feasible, but that has nothing to do with ambiguity.

Comment: Yes. But how can I eliminate ambiguity from this grammar?

Comment: there are lots of answers on [cs.se], which is a better place to ask questions not related to writing computer programs. For example, take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74467/finding-a-unambiguous-grammar and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64569/unambiguous-grammar-that-produce-equal-number-of-a-and-b